# Is the Visual Studio 2022 IDE's "toolbar" synchronized across PCs?

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Does anyone know if the Visual Studio 2022 IES's toolbar (see pic below) is synchronized on multiple PCs?

There is an option in (Tools)(Options)(Environment)(Accounts) called "`Synchronize Visual Studio settings across devices and installs on this machine`" Does this include the customizations made on the IDE's toolbar? (see pic below)

[image]

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm in the process of trying it but have to wait until I get home / at a different PC. I'm making all these toolbar customizations (at work) and kind of want to know (how) to get them to my other PCs?

Comment: Apparently the toolbar customizations do not synchronize automatically.  I'm at a different PC now and the VS Toolbar (in a C# project) did not synchronize with/from my work PC.  

Other customizations . .  (Tools)(Options)--(Environment)(Fonts and Colors)--(Displayed items)  synchronized perfectly tho

Comment: It seems the only way to move toolbar settings between VS installs on separate PCs is to use the (Tools)(Import and Export. . .) when importing, see the (Which settings to you want to import) question.  The toolbar settings are in the (General Settings) checkbox